# why is not const char put in rodata segment?

Tags: c, x86, char, compiler-construction

Having this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f(const char *str){
    char *p = (char*)str;
    *p=97;
}

int main(){
    char c;
    f(&c);

    char *p = malloc(10);
    if (p) { f(p); printf("p:%s\n",p); free(p); }

    const char d = 0; //only this part in interest
    f(&d); // here the function modifies the the char, but since it is NOT in rodata, no problem
    printf("d:%c\n",d);

    printf("c:%c\n",c);
}
```

Will generate gas:

```
...
.L3:
# a.c:16:   const char d = 0;
    movb    $0, -10(%rbp)   #, d
# a.c:17:   f(&d);
    leaq    -10(%rbp), %rax #, tmp98
    movq    %rax, %rdi  # tmp98,
    call    f   #
# a.c:18:   printf("d:%c\n",d);
    movzbl  -10(%rbp), %eax # d, d.0_1
    movsbl  %al, %eax   # d.0_1, _2
    movl    %eax, %esi  # _2,
    leaq    .LC1(%rip), %rdi    #,
    movl    $0, %eax    #,
    call    printf@PLT  #
# a.c:20:   printf("c:%c\n",c);
...
```

Here, the `d` const char variable is only `mov`ed to stack, but its name (rip location) is not in `.section .rodata`, why is that? When it has const modifier. Being it `char*` string, then it *is* placed automatically on rodata (char* does not even need const modifier). I have read somewhere constness is inherited (meaning once a variable is declared with const modifier, then even casting that cause cast-away-constness, does not change the constness - i.e. it will remain). But here the const char modifier is not even taken into account (directly manipulated via stack, as arrays are). Why?

Comment: It's a non-static const **local** variable, so it is stored on the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `d` is not static, but a function-local variable. If the function containing it is called multiple times (recursively, or concurrently in multiple threads), you get multiple instances of the variable (within the stack frame of the function), each of which has its own individual address, even though all of them contain the same data. The C standard requires these instances to be distinct. If you define the variable as `static`, the compiler might move it into the `.rodata` section, so that you only get one instance.

String literals (e.g. `"foo"`) however are not required to have individual addresses when they appear in (recursive) functions (unless they are used to initialize a `char` array), so the compiler usually places them into a `.rodata` section.

Comment: You say `The C standard requires these instances to be distinct` but afterwards, you say `String literals (e.g. "foo") however are not required to have individual addresses when they appear in (recursive) functions`. So char are required to have different addresses, whereas string not? I understand, why string should not be changed, but si should not be chars. Why does C standard require multiple instancies to have distinc address of that var?

Comment: There are no special rules about `char`. Think of it just like `ìnt`. If you have `const int x = 0;` in some recursive function, then `printf("%p",&x);` is required to print different addresses - just the same with `const char x = 0;`. That's just because local variables from different function invocations may not overlap - they are _local_ after all! Also, I'm not sure C forbids writing to local `const` variables, as C doesn't have "proper" constants... Since string literals are not intended to be changed, there is no requirement for individual addresses, except for `const char x[]="foo";`.

Comment: @Erlkoenig can you explain please why I get `segmentation fault` instead of `assignment of read-only variable ‘d’` when I add static to it ... It should be at .ro after it, right?

Comment: ISO C says it's UB to modify an object that was originally declared `const`, regardless of static or automatic storage.  In practice only take advantage of this to put static const data in read-only memory so violating this will crash.  But violating the other guarantee could lead to later code "not noticing" a change to a const var.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/fh67Le shows doing constant-propagation across a function call even though you I pass `&n` to a non-inline function.

Comment: @Erlkoenig a pointer `char*` is shared between muplitple instancies (e.g. recursive), but address it points not, that is understandable (as string should not change), however, why `const char x[]="foo";` (array - stored at stack) *is changable* between mutiple instancies? I know every instance make its own stack, but still *string literal* should not change even then. Does it mean that every instance of program (fork, or recurs) *copy* the whole string literal from the parent stack?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that `str` actually points to a constant variable; it might be a pointer to a non-`const` that was casted to `const char*`. By casting away the `const`, you suppress any compiler errors. You get `segmentation fault` because the variable becomes actually read-only when it is `static`, because the OS protects the `.rodata` section.

Comment: You can cast away `const` from a pointer as long as the original pointed-to object is not `const`, so this promise of not being modified only works where you're declaring the object itself, not just in a function that passes along a `const char *p` to another function.

Comment: When you do `const char x[]="foo";`, you allocate a new array on the stack, into which the string literal is _copied_, from the string literal that is in `.rodata`. A recursive function with such an array will result in the string existing multiple times in memory. You can omit the `const` here and the functions may modify the array (since each function invocation has its own array).

Comment: @Erlkoenig that means, that making an array const, is redundant. So `const char str[] = "abcd"` ok be simply without const modifier, right?

Comment: It is kind of redundant yes, unless you actually need multiple arrays with different addresses but identical contents. Yes, without `const` you get a local writable array that contains a copy of the string literal.

Comment: @Erlkoenig In what case would I need to have different address but identical contents? In both way, I have the right contenct (either by copying it as local, or const array which points to the same address), the only reason I can think of why to use one way over the other is for efficiency, but the should not  bother

Comment: I don't know a specific use case, but C provides a way to do that, i.e. there is no special exception for a `char` array initialized from a string literal. A `const` array can be initialized from a variable, in which case the contents _would_ differ.

Comment: "If you have `const int x = 0;` in some recursive function, then `printf("%p",&x);` is required to print different addresses - just the same with `const char x = 0;`" Do you happen to know why the standard requires this behavior, or how it can be useful?

Comment: It probably just follows from the other rules. Non-cost local variables are always individual, const local variables with variable initialization too, and there is no exception to make const local variables with fixed initialization identical. Use `static` if you want that.